# Why postgres changes the order after updating record django postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm updating a record in my Postgres database but I don't know why after updating the record Postgres changes the order of the updated row in the DB, I have attached the example below.

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PATCH'])
def tag_detail(request, project_id, tag_id):
    if request.method == 'PATCH':
        tag = Tag.objects.get(project_id=project_id, pk=tag_id)
        tag.ship_date = request.data.get('ship_date', tag.ship_date)
        tag.save()
        return Response("ok")
```

before update order:

```
Record 1
Record 2
Record 3
```

let's assume we have updated "Record 2", so the order will be:

```
Record 1
Record 3
Record 2
```

Comment: Since you do not use an `ORDER BY` clause, the database can return the records in any possible order. Often updated records end up as first or last object, but the order can be seen as an "implementation detail", and can also depend on indices used to retrieve the result.

Comment: Rows in a table don't have any implied order. The **only** way to get a guaranteed sorter order is to use `order by`

Comment: Excellent example of why you should use `ORDER BY` if the ordering of the rows is important to the app.